# Database Firewall rule at schema level

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Can we create database firewall rule in azure SQL data warehouse at schema level.

I need to restrict user on schema basis in same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#overview),

> SQL Data Warehouse only supports **server-level IP firewall rules** and
>   does not support database-level IP firewall rules.